# How to calculate Non-Latin language text width in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am using the following code to get the size of Urdu language but it is calculating the wrong width, please help me to find the correct width of Urdu string.

```
 CGSize size = [str sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq" size:18.0f]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following methods. They use `CoreText`.

Get height of specific text, constrained to a specific width:

```
- (CGFloat) heightWithAttributedString:(NSAttributedString*)renderedAttributedText maxWidth:(CGFloat) width {

    if (!renderedAttributedText) {

        return 0.0;
    }

    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFTypeRef)(renderedAttributedText));

    CGSize suggestedSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), NULL, CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX), NULL);

    CFRelease(framesetter);

    return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

Get width of specific text, constrained to a specific height:

```
- (CGFloat) widthWithAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)renderedAttributedText maxHeight:(CGFloat)height {

    if (!renderedAttributedText) {

        return 0.0;
    }

    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFTypeRef)(renderedAttributedText));

    CGSize suggestedSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), NULL, CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, height), NULL);

    CFRelease(framesetter);

    return suggestedSize.width;
}
```